# After a successful login, I want to be redirected to the screen I was on before I logged in. getLoginRedirect() does not work

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-4.x

Suppose you were in the user list screen. From there you will go to the login screen to log in. There, you will enter your email and password and enter the submit button.
You have successfully logged in.
If the login is successful, we want to be redirected to the user list screen.

If you were in the user details screen, you will be redirected to the user details screen by
If the user was on the edit screen, the user editing screen

I have read the AuthenticationPlugin documentation at book.cakephp.org.
There I learned to use `getLoginRedirect()` to achieve this functionality.

I am aware that what I want to do will happen once I set up in the steps below.

However, getLoginRedirect() returns null.

What do I need to do?
What am I missing?
What's wrong?

```php
// in Application.php

public function getAuthenticationService(ServerRequestInterface $request): AuthenticationServiceInterface
    {
        $path = $request->getPath();
        $authenticationService = new AuthenticationService([
            'unauthenticatedRedirect' => '/',
            'queryParam' => 'redirect',                // <- I believe this is the only one that matters.
        ]);

       // Abbreviated below....
}
```

```php
// in UsersController 

public function login()
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['get', 'post']);

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $result      = $this->Authentication->getResult();
            $requestData = $this->request->getData();

            if ($result->isValid()) {

                // I want to get the original url. But null is passed.
                $redirect = $this->Authentication->getLoginRedirect() ?? '/';

                return $this->redirect($redirect);
            }

            if ($this->request->is('post') && !$result->isValid()) {
                $this->Flash->error(__('メールアドレス、またはパスワードが間違っています。'));
            }
        }
    }
```

I think I've disclosed everything related to getLoginRedirect(). If there is something missing or something you are curious about, please feel free to let me know.

Please help me. Please help me...

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "_From there you will go to the login screen to log in_"? If you manually visit the login endpoint, then you won't get a redirect URL.

Comment: The flow is [GET -> login -> POST -> login -> login success or login failure].To elaborate a bit more, first go through the login action in the GET communication, enter the email and password in the login of the template, and press the submit button. Next, you can go through the login action in POST communication and log in.
What you are saying, ndm, is that we should separate the action for GET and POST?

Comment: For now I'm not yet really trying to say anything about any possible solution, I'm just saying that if you're visiting the login action yourself, ie not because of an automatic redirect that happens when you're not authenticated, then there will be no redirect information available. Hence I'm asking how exactly you're ending up at the login endpoint, not by what HTTP method, but by what actions that either you as the user, or your application performs.

Comment: Thank you.
And I'm sorry.
What is a login endpoint?

Comment: And endpoint in the context of a web application is basically just a URL, so the login endpoint is the URL where your login form is being displayed / where you perform the login process.

Comment: Oh, I see!
How do you get to the "/login" URL?
In the header of the "Users/show" screen, there is a <a> tag for 'Sign in'. Pressing it will take you to the "login" screen.
If you click on it, you will be taken to the "login" screen, where you can enter various information, and then click the "Sing in" button to log in. 
Thanks to npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login redirect functionality provided by the plugin only works automatically when you are being redirected to the login URL after accessing a URL that requires authentication while not being logged in. In that case the authentication middleware will set the `redirect` query string variable with the current URL, so that the component can pick it up after the redirect to the login URL.

If you manually visit the login URL, then you'd also need to manually set the `redirect` query string variable, ie in your menu where you build the link that takes you to the login, add the current URL to the query string, something along the lines of this:

```php
$service = $this->request->getAttribute('authentication');
// here `$queryParam` would by default be `redirect`
$queryParam = $service->getConfig('queryParam');

echo $this->Html->link('Login', [
    'plugin' => null,
    'prefix' => false,
    'controller' => 'Users',
    'action' => 'login',
    '?' => [
        $queryParam => $this->request->getRequestTarget(),
    ],
]);
```

So if you're on `/users/show`, the login link's URL would look something like:

```
/login?redirect=/users/show
```

and the form helper that builds your login form should pick up that exact URL, so that after submitting the form, the authentication component can read the redirect URL from the current URL accordingly.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Html > Creating Links](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)**

Comment: Thank you very much, ndm, for your sincerity and kindness. I really appreciate it. I will read it when I get home after work today.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I see! Thank you so much!
It's very easy to understand. I guess I misunderstood getLoginRedirect(). Thank you very much.
I'm sorry that my StackOverflow rating is not high enough to give it a high rating....

Comment: No need to apologize, everything's fine :) @IjIj